# pdftooltip color assign

Tags: color, pdf, pdfcomment

How can we assign a color for the pdftooltip ? For example I want the text CD to be blue. How can I get the color of my choice in RGB?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\begin{document}
% \pdftooltip{<text>}{<tooltip>}
\begin{align*}
  \mathrlap{\pdftooltip[mathstyle=\displaystyle]{\phantom{\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n}{2}(n+1)}}{sum\string_\{i=1\}\string^n i=tfrac\{n\}\{2\}(n+1)}}%
  \sum_{i=1}^n i &= \tfrac{n}{2}(n+1) \\
  \mathrlap{\pdftooltip[mathstyle=\displaystyle]{\phantom{E=mc^2}}{E=mc\textasciicircum 2}}%
  E &= mc^2\\
\end{align*}

\begin{itemize}
    \item This is  \pdftooltip{CD}{Compact disk}.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want `CD` to be blue, or `Compact disk` to be blue? Why include other `\pdftooltip`s in math mode? Do they have anything to do with this question?

Comment: Yes I want CD to be blue, No I just added that as an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the [`xcolor` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) to your preamble

```
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
```

and use

```
\pdftooltip{\textcolor{blue}{CD}}{Compact disk}
```

Here is a complete, minimal working example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment,xcolor}
\begin{document}
This is \pdftooltip{\textcolor{blue}{CD}}{Compact disk}.
\end{document}
```